# Java program loops twice without prompting

Tags: java, loops

Now this question might of been asked before on here, but I couldn't find it. So I apologise.

For some reason, my code seems to run twice, even though through out the code I only ask for input once. Can someone please guide me to my mistake?

Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMI 
{

    static Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    System.out.println("Height in inches: " + heightInInches());
    System.out.println("Weight in pounds: " + weightInPounds());
    System.out.println(outputBMI(heightInInches(),weightInPounds()));
}

public static int heightInInches()
{

    System.out.print("Enter your height in feet: ");
    int feet = kybd.nextInt(); 

    //feet validation
    while(feet < 2 || feet > 7)
    {
        System.out.println("Input not vaild.");

        System.out.print("Enter your height in feet: ");
        feet = kybd.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.print("Enter your height in inches: ");
    int inches = kybd.nextInt();

    //inches validation
    while(inches < 0 || inches > 13){
        System.out.println("Input not vaild.");
        System.out.print("Enter your height in inches: ");
        inches = kybd.nextInt();
    }

    int totalInches = inches + (feet * 12);

    return totalInches;

}

public static int weightInPounds()
{
    System.out.print("Enter your weight in stone: ");
    int stone = kybd.nextInt();

    //stone validation
    while(stone < 3 || stone > 30)
    {
        System.out.println("Input invalid.");
        System.out.print("Enter your height in stone: ");
        stone = kybd.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.print("Please enter your weight in pounds: ");
    int pounds = kybd.nextInt();

    //pounds validation
    while(pounds < 0 || pounds > 30)
    {
        System.out.println("Input invalid.");
        System.out.print("Please enter your weight in pounds: ");
        pounds = kybd.nextInt();
    }

    int totalPounds = pounds + (stone * 14);

    return totalPounds;
}

public static double outputBMI(double height, double weight)
{
    double BMI = (weight * 703)/(height/height);

    return BMI;
}
```

}

Comment: In your 3rd `println` in main method. You are calling `heightInInches( )` and `wightInPounds( )` again. You should have save the return values in your first call and send them to the `outputBMI( )` method

Comment: You don't only ask for input once. You call `heightInInches()` multiple times and each time you call it, it asks for input.

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet I'm confused as to what you mean? If it helps my objective is to call the height in inches and display that. Call the weight in pounds and display that. Then calculate the BMI and display that.

Comment: Every time you call `heightInInches()`, you are asking them to enter their height. And you're calling `heightInInches()` **again** inside `outputBMI()`. What you should do is to save the value you get from `heightInInches()` the first time in a variable, and use the variable as a parameter inside `outputBMI()`.

Comment: @Gendarme think I've sorted it. So I was declaring values where I'd declared the Scanner. Then assigned them that way.

static Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
    
static int totalInches;
static int totalPounds;

Answer (score 0):

As many mentionned in the comments you need to call your `heightInInches` and `weightInPounds` only once and store the values in some local variables in your main method then you reuse these variable wherever needed. You could for example update your main method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    int height = heightInInches();
    int weight = weightInPounds();
    System.out.println("Height in inches: " + height);
    System.out.println("Weight in pounds: " + weight);
    System.out.println(outputBMI(height,weight));
}
```